# Crockford Prototypical Inheritance

Tags: javascript

In the following article, Douglas Crockford creates a function to more closely simulate prototypical inheritance in JavaScript (http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html).  I understand the concept.  However, once you create a new object using the function below, how do you then add methods and properties to that object other than using dot/subscript notation.  Either of which, in my opinion, would produce ugly code.

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

Do I then need to use the following notation?

```
newObject.method1 = function(){}
newObject.cnt = 1;
...
```

Does anyone else find this as an ugly way to add properties and methods to an object?

I understand I can technically pass in a function, for which I want to set the prototype of, with all the methods and variables.

I'm more or less trying to understand how Crockford intended for that function to be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
var prototypeForNewObject = {
  method: function (x) { ... },
  prototypeProperty: 42
};

var newObject = Object.create(prototypeForNewObject);

// Adding an instance property
newObject.cnt = 1;
```

And instead of using Crock's version, I would use the full EcmaScript 5 signature that includes an optional `propertiesObj` argument.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

You might find the examples at that link informative.

Comment: Good to know about.  That's more or less how I would expect the function signature to look like.  Just trying to understand how Crock intented the function to be used.

Comment: @Steve, your best bet to understand his intent might be to send him an email at the address at the top of the page to which you linked.  My avatar is a stuffed (and rather fat) t-rex eating a jar of vegemite.  T-rex forelimbs are not good at opening jars, so it has to eat the jar whole.

Comment: That is ridiculous...Everyone knows that t-rex's do not eat vegemite.  Maybe Crock should come on StackOverflow instead.